# HIghcharts onclick change xAxis plotline according to some value

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have to shift my xAxis plotline according to Some specific time which could be described outside of the Graph using Onclick Event. Here my Code is

HTML Code

```
<li class="selected" onclick="exp_chng(this.id)" id="time1"><?php 
           date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
          echo date('H:i'); ?></li>
          <li onclick="exp_chng(this.id)" id="time2"><?php  $currentDate = strtotime(date('H:i'));   $futureDate = $currentDate+(60*1); echo $formatDate = date("H:i", $futureDate); ?> </li>

          <li onclick="exp_chng(this.id)" id="time3"><?php  $currentDate = strtotime(date('H:i'));   $futureDate = $currentDate+(60*2); echo $formatDate = date("H:i", $futureDate); ?></li>

          <li onclick="exp_chng(this.id)" id="time4"><?php  $currentDate = strtotime(date('H:i'));   $futureDate = $currentDate+(60*3); echo $formatDate = date("H:i", $futureDate); ?></li>
```

And the Highcharts initialization is

xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',

```
             type: 'datetime',
            minTickInterval: 1000 * 60, //one minute

            gridLineWidth: 0.1,
            plotLines: [{
            value: exp_time, // Value of where the line will appear
            width: 2 ,
            color: '#A28F29',
            // dashStyle: 'dash',
            id: 'plotline1',
            label: {
                      text: 'Expiration time',
                      style: {
                        color: '#686A3B',
                        //#A28F29
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                      }
                    }
        }]
        },
```

Javascript code

```
function exp_chng(id)
{
  var time = $('#'+id).html();


  var chart = $("#tv_chart_container").highcharts();
  chart.xAxis[0].removePlotLine('plotline1');


  var check_1 =chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
              value: time,
              color: '#A28F29',
              width: 2,
              id: 'plotline1', 
              label: {
                text: 'Expiration time',
                style: {
                  color: '#686A3B',

                  fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
              }
          });
  console.log(check_1);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? does this not work? do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: In console no error, already created plotline is removed correctly but the new addplotline cannot be added

Comment: can you stick a breakpoint after `var time = $('#'+id).html();` and tell what's the value of `time`?

Comment: time will be taken in "H:i" format for eg., 15:56, 15:57

Comment: that is the reason it doesn't draw a plotline. it needs the datetime in milliseconds to draw the plotLine. create a date object from your datetime and then set the value.